# select option menu reading from database - smarty,php

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I've got a database with a categories that I want to put into a select option menu with smarty

in my news.model I've got that function

```
function  getCategoriesNews(){
       $sql = "SELECT name,id, FROM categories WHERE id>0 ORDER BY ID ";
       return $this->db->GetAll($sql);
   }
```

Where I read the categories from the database. In my template add_news.tpl I want to put them here

```
<select name="categories" id="news_cat">
        <option value="0"></option>  
        {foreach from=$news item=i}                              
            <option value="" ></option>            
        {/foreach}    
      </select>
```

But I don't know how I tried different ways but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Query. Replace `ORDER BY id` instead of `ORDER BY ID`

```
 $sql = "SELECT name,id, FROM categories WHERE id>0 ORDER BY id ";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the php page where you are calling the getCategoriesNews() function,
assign the result in a variable,

```
$categories = getCategoriesNews();
```

Then assign this array to the template

```
if(!empty($categories[0]))
    $tplObj->assign('categories',$categories); //smarty variable without $
```

Then in your tpl file use it as follows,

considering you have catId,cat fields

```
<select name="categories" id="news_cat">
        <option value="0"></option>
  {if $categories != ''}
        {foreach from=$categories item=i}                              
            <option value="{$i.catId}" >{$i.cat}</option>            
        {/foreach}
  {/if}
</select>
```